# displays data from another websites ex. www.dx.com

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to make a website (C# ASP.NET WebForms) that displays data from another websites ex. www.dx.com , www.play.com , www.ebay.com . I want to have an administration panel to launch spiders for each URL or for each category of products. Purpose of my website is to dispaly products with price under 100 USD.
My question is: How can i display each product, price, product description photo of product in my website. Tell me a way: a tutorial or a piece of code in C# because i am newbie IN WEB CRAWLERS.

Thanks to all

Comment: This is way too broad of a subject for stackoverflow's format. I suggest you look into HTML Agility Pack for this.

Comment: This is too broad of a question for Stack Overflow. You need to make your own attempt to write a crawler, and break your problem into smaller pieces. If you get stuck on a specific part, then that would be a more appropriate thing to ask about.